# How to add a table with predicted data & dates in Python?

Tags: python

I found a model which predicts the price of stocks as you can see below. I would like to see the actual values of the predictions. I have two questions to more experienced colleagues :)

1. Could you tell me how to create a table with values of predicted price and dates?
2. How to tune the model? ( I mean the number of LSTM units and Dense)

Thank you very much!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, GRU
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.random import set_seed

from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

set_seed(455)
np.random.seed(455)

end = datetime.now()
start = datetime(2016, end.month, end.day)
dataset = yf.download("MSFT", start, end)

tstart = 2016
tend = 2020

def train_test_plot(dataset, tstart, tend):
    dataset.loc[f"{tstart}":f"{tend}", "High"].plot(figsize=(16, 4), legend=True)
    dataset.loc[f"{tend+1}":, "High"].plot(figsize=(16, 4), legend=True)
    

def train_test_split(dataset, tstart, tend):
    train = dataset.loc[f"{tstart}":f"{tend}", "High"]
    test = dataset.loc[f"{tend+1}":, "High"]
    return train, test

def train_test_split_values(dataset, tstart, tend):
    train, test =  train_test_split(dataset, tstart, tend)
    return train.values, test.values

training_set, test_set = train_test_split_values(dataset, tstart, tend)


sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
training_set = training_set.reshape(-1, 1)
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

def split_sequence(sequence, window):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        end_ix = i + window
        if end_ix > len(sequence) - 1:
            break
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

window_size = 60
features = 1

X_train, y_train = split_sequence(training_set_scaled, window_size)

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],features)


model_lstm = Sequential()
model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=128, activation="tanh", input_shape=(window_size, features), return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=128, activation="tanh"))
model_lstm.add(Dense(128))
model_lstm.add(Dense(64))
model_lstm.add(Dense(units=1))

model_lstm.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model_lstm.summary()
print(model_lstm)

model_lstm.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32)

dataset_total = dataset.loc[:,"High"]
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(test_set) - window_size :].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1, 1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)

X_test, y_test = split_sequence(inputs, window_size)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], features)
predicted_stock_price = model_lstm.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
y_test = sc.inverse_transform(y_test)


def return_rmse(test, predicted):
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, predicted))
    print("The root mean squared error is {:.2f}.".format(rmse))

return_rmse(y_test,predicted_stock_price)'''
```